# How to import dropdown with autocomplete in the navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Im really new in the react and may be my code is very wrong, but how can create a dropdown with autocomplete in the navbar with bootstrap in React JS.

I read too much examples but my code never run..

I try to create dropdown with create-select but I dont know exactly how..

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import createClass from 'create-react-class';


export default class Header extends Component {

  var ValuesAsBooleansField = createClass({
    displayName: 'ValuesAsBooleansField',
    propTypes: {
      label: PropTypes.string
    },
    getInitialState () {
      return {
        options: [
          { value: true, label: 'Yes' },
          { value: false, label: 'No' }
        ],
        value: null
      };
    },
    onChange(value) {
      this.setState({ value });
      console.log('Boolean Select value changed to', value);
    },
    render () {
      return (
        <div className="section">
          <h3 className="section-heading">{this.props.label} <a href="https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/tree/master/examples/src/components/BooleanSelect.js">(Source)</a></h3>
          <Select
            onChange={this.onChange}
            options={this.state.options}
            simpleValue
            value={this.state.value}
            />
          <div className="hint">This example uses simple boolean values</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  module.exports = ValuesAsBooleansField;

  render() {
    return (
      <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse ">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WeatherGraph</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Начало <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Времето</a>
            </li>      
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed up the Es5 and Es6 coding style. Just update your code and it's working fine now.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
export default class ValuesAsBooleansField extends Component {

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        options: [
          { value: true, label: 'Yes' },
          { value: false, label: 'No' }
        ],
        value: null
      }
      this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }
    onChange(event) {
      this.setState({value: event.value});
      console.log('Boolean Select value changed to', event.value);
    }

    render () {
      return (
        <div className="section">
          <h3 className="section-heading">{this.props.label} <a href="https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/tree/master/examples/src/components/BooleanSelect.js">(Source)</a></h3>
          <Select
            onChange={this.onChange}
            options={this.state.options}
            value={this.state.value}
            />
          <div className="hint">This example uses simple boolean values</div>
        </div>
      );
    }

}
```

****************    Paste this code in Header.js file *************

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ValuesAsBooleansField from './ValuesAsBooleansField';

export default class Header extends Component {



    render() {
      return (
        <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse ">
          <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" 
            type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
            data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <ValuesAsBooleansField />
          <a class="navbar-brand" >WeatherGraph</a>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link">Начало <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">Времето</a>
              </li>      
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: I copy this code and paste in my Header.jsx but I have error on the 

Header Class..

Can you see at this link:

https://ibb.co/jsBA8H

Comment: you have pasted comment also. please removed [Header class] comment. paste both the code in seprate file with same name as component name. this will work

Comment: Ca explain to me where is the component name... :(

Comment: create two files with Header.js  and ValuesAsBooleansField.js name. and paste code to respective file. and import Header  where you want to place Header.

Comment: js or jsx ? :))

Comment: I have this error:

./src/components/common/ValuesAsBooleansField.jsx
  Line 5:   'Component' is not defined               no-undef

Can you check

https://ibb.co/evGCqx

Comment: When I import react component, i have this error:
./src/components/common/ValuesAsBooleansField.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-select' in 'C:\Users\Master\Desktop\react-app\src\components\common'

Comment: import Component in your Header and install  react-select dependency. its quite simple. you need to read tutorials and then try basic examples.